# Trying to Join 6 Tables

Tags: sql-server, join

I may be trying something too ambitious, but am trying it anyway: I'm trying to join 6 different tables. Below is the SQL Statement

```
SELECT 
AF.[Product Number], 
AF.[Week End Date], 
AF.[Inv Change Cost], 
AF.[Gross Sales Lbs], 
AF.[Production Lbs], 
ACO.CO2, 
ACO.Oil, 
MC.[Actual Usage Cost], 
SC.[Actual Usage Cost], 
AP.[Direct Lab Wkly Cst] * (1 +(AP.[Fringes Wkly Cst] / (AP.[Direct Lab Wkly Cst] + AP.[Indirect Lab Wkly Cst]))) AS DirecLaborCost, 
AP.[Indirect Lab Wkly Cst] * (1 +(AP.[Fringes Wkly Cst] / (AP.[Direct Lab Wkly Cst] + AP.[Indirect Lab Wkly Cst]))) AS IndirectLaborCost, 
AP.[Variable Wkly Cst], 
AP.[Freezing Wkly Cst], 
AP.[Packaging Wkly Cst], 
AP.[Fixed Wkly Cst], 
AP.[Non Processing Wkly Cst], 
SP.[Direct Lab Wkly Cst], 
SP.[Indirect Lab Wkly Cst], 
AP.[Fringes Wkly Cst], 
SP.[Variable Wkly Cst], 
SP.[Freezing Wkly Cst], 
SP.[Packaging Wkly Cst], 
SP.[Fixed Wkly Cst], 
SP.[Non Processing Wkly Cst] 
FROM Table1 AF 
JOIN Table2 ACO ON AF.[Product Number] = ACO.[Product Number] 
JOIN Table3 MC ON MC.[Product Number] = ACO.[Product Number] 
JOIN Table4 SC ON SC.[Product Number] = MC.[Product Number] 
JOIN Table5 AP ON AP.[Product Num] = SC.[Product Number] 
JOIN Table6 SP ON SP.[Product Num] = AP.[Product Num] 
WHERE (AF.[Week End Date] = '2/4/2017');
```

I am currently getting an SQL Timeout Error. Is the statement too long, or am I making a syntax mistake?

EDIT:

I've discovered that I'm getting a timeout due to the sheer amount of records. I've significantly narrowed my query down to 16 records using the following Query:

```
SELECT
AF.[Product Number],
AF.[Week End Date],
AF.[Inv Change Cost],
AF.[Gross Sales Lbs],
AF.[Production Lbs],
MC.[Actual Usage Cost] AS MeatCost,
SC.[Actual Usage Cost] AS SeasoningCost,
ACO.[CO2],
ACO.[Oil],
AP.[Direct Lab Wkly Cst],
AP.[Indirect Lab Wkly Cst],
AP.[Fringes Wkly Cst],
AP.[Variable Wkly Cst],
AP.[Freezing Wkly Cst],
AP.[Packaging Wkly Cst],
AP.[Fixed Wkly Cst],
AP.[Non Processing Wkly Cst],
SP.[Direct Lab Wkly Cst],
SP.[Indirect Lab Wkly Cst],
SP.[Fringes Wkly Cst],
SP.[Variable Wkly Cst],
SP.[Freezing Wkly Cst],
SP.[Packaging Wkly Cst],
SP.[Fixed Wkly Cst],
SP.[Non Processing Wkly Cst]
FROM Table1 AF
FULL JOIN Table2 MC ON MC.[Week Ending Date] = AF.[Week End Date] AND MC.[Product Number] = AF.[Product Number]
FULL JOIN Table3 SC ON SC.[Week Ending Date] = AF.[Week End Date] AND SC.[Product Number] = AF.[Product Number]
FULL JOIN Table4 ACO ON ACO.[Product Number] = AF.[Product Number] AND ACO.[Week Ending Date] = AF.[Week End Date]
FULL JOIN Table5 AP ON AP.[Product Num] = AF.[Product Number] AND AP.[Week Ending Date] = AF.[Week End Date]
FULL JOIN Table6 SP ON SP.[Product Num] = AF.[Product Number] AND SP.[Week Ending Date] = AF.[Week End Date]
WHERE (AF.[Product Number] = '96443' AND AF.[Week End Date] = '2/4/2017' AND 
MC.[Rout Line Name] = 'Total Cost' AND SC.[Rout Line Name] = 'Total Cost')
```

As I've stated before, I have narrowed this down to 16 lines, but I want to get a full 1-line record

I believe what is happening is MC, SC, AP and SP are all returning two records, but I'm not how to sum these values up to have them all on a single line

Comment: Are you missing an asterisk after `AP.[Indirect Lab Wkly Cst] ` ?

Comment: I literally just saw that! Thanks! That problem is solved! But now I'm still getting the timeout error. Is my statement too long?

Comment: I'm betting your getting to many rows by only joining on `[Product Num]`

Comment: Why are you storing dates as strings?

Comment: Not my DB. They did a few interesting things

Comment: Well if it is too slow you need to look at the execution plan to determine why it is slow. It could be a dozen or more things. Missing/poor indexes, stale statistics, implicit datatype conversions....etc.... Can you post the actual execution plan, not the estimated one? You will have to run it in SSMS as a timeout is a symptom of an application, the database will run the query until it gets a result.

Comment: I'll fire up SSMS and check it out. Thanks!

Comment: You can try only selecting the top 1 and viewing the execution plan to check for missing/poorly optimized indexes.

Comment: Please read and act on [mcve]. Is product number PK/UNIQUE in all those tables? Eg if it appears in a compound PK then you likely want to JOIN ON equalities for each other PK/FK column name for each PK-FK table pair.

Comment: No PK's at all in any of these tables :(